# send notification to another phone

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, notifications

i've been doing on my project which i should send a notification from my device to the other device.

lets say : i've got a edittext, when i insert a number greater than 140 and press the submit button, my device will send a notification to the another device, so a notif will appears on the other device. anyone know how to connected these devices?

well, i've been thinking using webservices/server/internet to connected it, does anyone know how to do it? it'll be more helpfull if u can show me the example code, thanks before :D

Comment: try push notification or c2dm.

Comment: can u show me the example? thanks before

Comment: [Send Notifications / Alerts From Android Phone to Desktop PC](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/send-notifications-alerts-from-android-phone-to-desktop-pc/) [Android push notifications (tutorial)](http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/10/07/android-push-notifications-tutorial/) [c2dm tutorials](http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/03/simple-google-android-c2dm-tutorial-push-notifications-for-android/) [for notification and code](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) also http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

Comment: Use C2DM. For sample code go to http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Answer (score 2):

Just use pushbullet:

http://www.pushbullet.com/.
When you install pushbullet you can also install Push Tasker (so you can do Task when you receive certain notifications).