# How can i send push notification from android device in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to send push notification from my android device. How can i do this? I need code for send push notification from android device.

Comment: Where do you want to send the notifications to?

Comment: Hey here is the code for that.please visit this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276342/android-c2dm-push-notification

Comment: possible duplicate of [send notification to another phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420418/send-notification-to-another-phone)